# How to convert Base64 to pdf on Safari and IE?

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I have a javascript function to convert Base64 to pdf below:

```
function toViewPdfHtml(stringBase64) {
            var objbuilder = '';
            objbuilder += ('<object width="100%" height="100%"      data="data:application/pdf;base64,');
            objbuilder += (stringBase64);
            objbuilder += ('" type="application/pdf" class="internal">');
            objbuilder += ('<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,');
            objbuilder += (stringBase64);
            objbuilder += ('" type="application/pdf" />');
            objbuilder += ('</object>');

            return objbuilder;
        }
```

This function run normally on Chrome, but when I try running in Safari, the function not work normally (it does not have scroll for pdf file, so I cannot see all document). And in IE it does not work.

Anyone can help me resolve to run normally in Safari and IE?
Thanks.

Comment: use [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Comment: @JaromandaX, How can I use pdf.js in function above ?